# Must choose 1 of 2 radio buttons to continue validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The validation is needed to block the user to continue to the next page. They must have check one of the radio buttons etc.

```
<div class="">
    <div class="radiho" style="display: block">
        <input type="checkbox" name="speakenglish" value="true" id="speakenglish" class="yeseng">
        <label for="speakenglish" class="radio-label">Yes please.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="rahdio" style="display: block">
        <input type="checkbox" name="speakenglish" value="false" id="dontspeakenglish" class="noeng" checked>
        <label for="dontspeakenglish" class="radio-label"> No thank you, not at this time.</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have some JS that works with the .req class, but that just makes both boxes have to be checked which is wrong. The bottom one I tried to use but the page just skipped validation totally and went onto the next page.

```
thisObj.find('input[type=checkbox].req').each(function () {

    if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        empty = true;
        $(this).siblings('label').addClass('error');
    }
});

thisObj.find('input[type=checkbox].yeseng' || 'input[type=checkbox].noeng').each(function () {

    if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        empty = true;
        $(this).siblings('label').addClass('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Wrap these in a radio button group, and make the group as required

Comment: changed to radio group. validation comes up. input[type=checkbox].yeseng allows me to go through, input[type=checkbox].noeng doesnt.

Comment: thisObj.find('input[type=radio].yeseng' || 'input[type=radio].noeng').each(function () only allows the first input to be checked for validation, so my problem is the OR operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out so you must check at least one box.

```
    thisObj.find('input[type=radio].engdriver' ).each(function () {

    if(!thisObj.find('input[type=radio].engdriver:checked').val()) {
        empty = true;
        $(this).siblings('label').addClass('error');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for the yeseng/noeng selector you want:

```
thisObj.find('input[type=checkbox].yeseng,input[type=checkbox].noeng')
```

or:

```
thisObj.find('input[type=checkbox].yeseng').add('input[type=checkbox].noeng')
```

Comment: The same still happens, Validation doesn't allow me to press the no english checkbox. changed to radio buttons. and still wont allow me to continue.

Comment: What does `alert(thisObj.find('input[type=checkbox].yeseng').length);` return and `alert(thisObj.find('input[type=checkbox].noeng');` return?  Put those statements right before the selector.

Comment: I will check them out very soon again.

Comment: both return values of 0

Comment: That means there is a problem with the selector; thisObj is not the parent of the `.yeseng` or `.noeng` checkboxes.  So where does thisObj come from?

Comment: function fcbValidate(thisObj) {

    console.log('Validating', thisObj);

    var empty       = false;
    var identical   = false;
    var nonidentical= false;
    var invalidemail= false;
    var invalidnum  = false;
    var past        = false;
    var tooSoon     = false;var needcheck   = false;
    var packagestime= false; Cant seem to add a simple code block LOL. But here is the function for thisObj.  Then lists all the validation under etc.

Comment: OK so then what gets passed into fcbValidate method?  Also what does your `console.log` statement say?

Comment: Sorry for the wait. Been really busy on other tasks. I will have to get back to you later on Brian

Comment: The console shows that the length stays at 1 if any of the two are clicked on.

Comment: cannot for the life of me understand when the two statements are seperated, they get validated, when joined together it completely fails